# SAPUI5 - Input border/frame

Tags: css, sapui5

I want to get rid of the frame that is around an `Input` in SAPUI5 framework. I want to make an input field elevated but the frame around the input field makes it not like desired.[image]

I have tried it using `CSS` like this:

```
.cityInput{
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: none;
    min-height: 27px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #808888;
}
```

I want to get rid of the two yellow lines that surrounds the input field.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe `border:none;` ?

Comment: Actually, border:none is already there.

Comment: Oh right, didn't see it, i suppose that could a default margin, would be much easier to know what it is if you could include the markup

Comment: If you use the chrome debugger and inspect the element you may find that your css file is not the last css rule being applied. Have you checked this to see what styles are being applied from where for this particular element?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you want to get rid of the default (silver/grey) border around the input box. If this is the case then I would suggest making the border color same as your background. Making border=none, on the input class, directly does not work.

```
.cityInput .sapMInputBaseInner {
      border: 1px solid #fdf6b1;
}
```